# Visibility of Methods and their cost

Tags: java, visibility

I recently read [this article](https://realm.io/news/360andev-jake-wharton-java-hidden-costs-android/) by Jake Wharton. This is targeted at Android, but also perfectly valid for java I think.

Consider the following code:

```
public class A {

    private String someField = "abc";

    class B {

        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println(someField);
        }

    }
}
```

We have a simple class A and an inner class B (This has a reference to A and can acccess its members). Class B is accessing the field `someField` in A even though it is private. According to the article, this is done by the compiler generating `synthetic accessor methods` which allow the inner class to access the field.
Now my way more basic question: Why does the compiler even care about visiblities when the code is compiled? As we have seen in this example, a new method is generated, which basically just introduces overhead.
Visibilities are a great thing for architecting good software, but if the compiler is done checking that everything is correct according to the declared visibilies, why not optimize those methods away (E.g. just taking everything for being public and allow calls to it)?
First I thought this was due to security reasons, but reflection allows the access of all fields, not caring for visibility as far as I know.

This might be a basic misunderstanding of me, if so, I would be happy if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: "Why does the compiler even care about visiblities when the code is compiled?" Well anything validating the code is likely to care, for one thing... of course, the JIT compiler is in a rather better place to inline the method calls, but that's a different matter. (Note that reflection can be disabled with a security manager - and that's enforced at *execution* time. You really don't want the compiler to emit code which will fail under some environments...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the compiler even care about visiblities when the code is compiled?

The JVM doesn't allows access to `private` methods/constructors/fields outside a class.  It has no special rule for nested classes which were added after this rule was designed.  Instead the compiler adds accessor methods so the language can support a means of access the JVM doesn't.

> As we have seen in this example, a new method is generated, which basically just introduces overhead.

Only if the method isn't called very much and isn't optimised.

Adding any simple method (On Hotspot, any method of 35 bytes or less) will be inlined very quickly and has no impact on performance (except if the maximum inline level is reached)

> why not optimize those methods away

It does this at runtime so that previous rules continue to be enforced.

> reflection allows the access of all fields, not caring for visibility as far as I know.

Though not by default, you have to explicitly want this as an option and not have a SecurityManager which prevents it.

Answer (score 0):

If compiler converts all private fields to public fields in compile time, one problem will be happened when your project is compiled into library and reused by others. In that case, all your private fields will become public.

There are some tools for optimizing this. In Android, there is a tool named `ProGuard` that will convert all getter/setter to direct field access.